# Is There any method by which I can call a method every time a new activity starts in an app?

Tags: java, android

I am using an external `jar` for some functionality in my Android project but I need to call the `initialize` function on every `onStart()` function. Is there a method, I can skip this step and it will automatically gets called every time a new activity start.

I am aware that some code injection techniques are available. Can some one please explain it in details or provide some source for it.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is Aspect Oriented Pragramming (AOP) for Andriod. For Web Applications, Springs framework can achieve that

Comment: Yes, I am also thinking of using AOP using Aspectj but I am new to it. Will update if I will be able to solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);`

Answer (score 0):

Make a class extend Activity class and put call to your library method in it's `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState);` method.

Now make all your custom activities in which you need to call your library method on create extend above class rather than extending Activity directly.

In short use Inheritance!

Comment: The problem with this approach is I already have my whole project and I need to modify each activity to extend the new activity class, I dont want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

`onCreate(Bundle bundle)` is the answer. You may also need to look for the `onResume` and `onStart` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You might acheive this by creating a custom Activity class and overiding its onStart method. Then extend all your Activities from this custom Activity.

```
    public class CustomActivity extends Activity{
       @Override
       protected void onStart() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onStart();
           // call your method.
       }

    }
```

and then extend your activities from this custom Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You do this as follows without modifying each activity.

Create a class which extends `android.app.Application` like

```
public class YourApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
         // do whatever start-up processes you want to perform in this method
    }
}
```

Next, modify the application manifest files as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="application.package"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <application
    ...
        android:name="application.package.YourApplication"
    ... >
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Hope this helps.